# HTTP Content-type header for any file

Tags: java, html, servlets, web

I have a requirement where I can upload any file (any file type) and on request I should send the file back to the browser. If the file is an image, I should display the image in the browser. If the file is of any other type, I should download the file. Please let me know the content-type that  should set for the above requirement in my servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use switch-case and set content type header accordingly.

something like:

```
switch(fileext){
case "jpg": ctype="image/jpg"; break;
case "gif": ctype = "image/gif"; break
default: 
ctype ="application/force-download";

}

header('Content-type: ' . $ctype);
```

Answer (score -1):

if uploaded stuff is an image then you would need to pass image URL in response to the browser. That's how you can render the image. So, "text/html" would be fine in response.

Jitendra